# Upgading ubuntu 18.04.6 to 20.04 on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

I have a dual booted computer, where I have windows on my main storage drive and ubuntu on another drive. This has worked pretty well, but now I want to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. I have read that when on dual boot it is best to just use the software updater gui to do this, but when I click the app it wont start. I tried restarting the computer, and apt update and upgrade.

I the reason I want to use the gui is that I got this message when going through the steps for upgrading in terminal from [this](https://www.linuxtechi.com/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-ubuntu-20-04-lts/) guide.
This is from running `sudo apt upgrade -y`

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-113-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-113-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-96-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-84-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/"ssd"/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

And got unsure if I would break something on my windows boot.
How can I get the gui to run or how should I proceed for upgrading my ubuntu version without breaking windows and deleting my files on the ubuntu boot drive.

I have tried this `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean -y` for fixing the gui with no luck.

Note: Im pretty new to ubuntu.

Comment: The part of the output from your `apt upgrade` command is a non-issue. However, without seeing the entire output of this command we can't tell if there may be problems. Always post the whole output of commands if you want help interpreting. Also, be aware that this command does not release upgrade-- it simply upgrades existing packages. This should be done *before* a release upgrade and it's also part of regular system maintenance.  If you don't want to lose your data, then **back up** because nobody is invulnerable to making mistakes

Comment: The output seemed to be good expect the part that I asked about. Can the data on my windows drives be corrupt/removed by doing this? As this is the only data im afraid of loosing. The data on the ubuntu drive is backed up on github so thats no problem.

Comment: Yes, you could make a mistake and lose your data. Always back up before installing/removing/upgrading an OS.

Comment: Even on completly different drives??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the GUI to the upgrade, but you are entering terminal commands. That's a little confusing.  The way that I upgrade is using the command line.

The dual boot things should not be impacted by the upgrade. Certainly your Windows boot partition wont be touched. **But read this carefully - you should back up your files on Ubuntu.** I have all my files on partitions other than the system ones so that an upgrade, or even a total reinstall, will not lose and of my files. If your `/home` directory is on the same partition as `/` then please do a backup of `/home`. If it all goes horribly wrong you will thank me!

Standard thing is to make sure you are up to date on the current release. You seem to be dong that, but for completeness:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Next, check whether upgrades to the distro are enabled. You are running 18.04 LTS (Long Term Support). Quite often those LTS distros are installed and configured not to update major versions. So you need to check if this is enable: You can use nano or vi for this:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Most of this file is explanatory comments, but the last line is the critical one. If its says `Prompt=never` then you would never get prompted to upgrade. Change that to `Prompt=lts` and save the file.

To do the upgrade you will need the upgrade-manager. If its not already installed you can install this with:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

And then you get to the real core of the upgrade. First, check that the upgrade will go ahead:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c
```

The `-c` flag says just check what can be upgraded. Nothing will change using this. Read what comes back. If you are happy, and wish to proceed, then execute the command with out that flag

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and follow the onscreen instructions.